# How to offline install of Spring Boot Tools Plugin into Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, spring-tools-4

I need to install Spring Tools 4 Plugin into my Eclipse IDE. The Problem is, that I dont have any Internet access on this machine. My other Plugins like SonarLint, MoreUnit I installed via zip archive available on official sites or github.

`Install New Software -> add archive.`

I cant find any zip archives for Spring Boot Tools 4. Is there a way to get it or another way to install that plugin offline?

I tried to download and install everything on another machine and copy it, but its forbidden to connect bigger usb drives to the machine. For the plugin itsef it will be ok.

Comment: Would installing from another (copied) installation via _File > Import: Install > From Existing Installation_ work for you? Otherwise, [an update sites or parts of it can also be downloaded via Eclipse from the command line](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-09/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_mirror.html?cp=2_0_20_3_0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the archived update site for STS 4.4.2 for Eclipse 2019-09:

https://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/sts4/update/4.4.2.RELEASE/e4.13/sts4-4.4.2.RELEASE-e4.13.0-updatesite.zip

It contains all the STS4 pieces and a bunch of additional plugins from Eclipse, we haven't really tested a full offline installation using purely this update site. Usually the install procedure contains other update sites while installing a feature in order to find missing dependencies. So in case you don't have internet access and the STS4 install requires a dependency that usually comes from the main Eclipse p2 repo, you might  run into this. In that case, please open a bug at https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues and we will fix that.

Hope this helps!